# Make adjacent div responsive to sibling's transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three `inline-block` divs on my page (see [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/ps7a0jv4/36/)):

[image]

Div `#one` contains a button 'Show' and is absolutely positioned so that it overlaps the div `#two`. When 'Show' is clicked, div `#two` slides out from under `#one` using `translateX`, like so:

[image]

When this happens, I would like to push div `#three` ***down*** so that it appears just below div `#two`, like so:

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about achieving this using pure CSS that doesn't involve moving `#three` along the Y-axis using `#three { transform: translateY(...) }`. I was wondering if `translateX` is the wrong approach here since it does not disturb the position of neighbouring elements, but I don't know what to use in its place.

Comment: seems your code working fine. `#three` appears below as `#two` slide out. What is the problem?

Comment: @gpl, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on me having to specify `translateY`.

Comment: Avoid using absolute positioning where possible, unless you have good reason not to, because it does not have a size in the static page content (it's like a different layer in a paint program). I.e. The blue diff should not be absolute. The design choice seems odd. Either make the content right all the time or let it say at the bottom anyway.

Comment: Thanks @F.Müller, the reason I have placed `#three` to the right of `#one` is because `#one` has a very large height and placing `#three` below it would force the user to have to scroll down the page in order to access it, which could be cumbersome. There is also the danger that the user could miss it altogether since it would be out of sight, out of mind. So I thought placing it to the right would not only make it easier to access but also more visible to the user. And since `#two` does not take up much space vertically, `#three` could easily slide below it when the user clicks `Show`.

Comment: @user51462 Okay, well it depends on what kind of information/content you are displaying. If it is the main content of the page in `#three` you should probably not touch it. I suggest going for something like you have in the second image. Otherwise, it kinda defeats the purpose of the show/hide mechanism. If the information in the `#two` is important, then why not embed it in the main content `#three` in the first place? You could design it like a toggleable spoiler-element.

Comment: @user51462 Please have a look at the fiddle that I have added to my answer (in the comment section) and let me know, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already stated in the comment section: It really depends on what your final goal is and what content you put in your divs - how everything is structured.

I feel like this is more of a XY-problem. I.e. the design-choice demands for a special case/solution that could be solved in another way so that the "hacky" solution does not have to exist in the first place.

Nevertheless, since you have asked for it I give you a solution for this specific problem:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const slide = document.getElementById('show');
const done = document.getElementById('hide');
const two = document.getElementById('two');
const right = document.querySelector('.right');

show.addEventListener('click', function() {
  two.classList.add('show');
  right.classList.add('shift');
});

hide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  two.classList.remove('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    right.classList.remove('shift');
  }, 1000)

});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.right.shift {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

#one,
#two {
  height: 100%;
}

#one {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#two {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#two.show {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div id="one">
    Click 'Show' to show panel 2
    <button type='button' id='show'>Show</button>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    Click 'Hide' to hide panel 2
    <button type='button' id='hide'>Hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">Some other content</div>
```

**Alternative**

You could implement a spoiler section that you can toggle to display more information if it is desired.

```js
const spoilerBtn = document.getElementById('spoiler-btn');
const spoiler = document.getElementById('spoiler');

spoilerBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  spoiler.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#spoiler {
  background-color: tomato;
  display: none;
}

#spoiler.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Aside text here</div>
<div class="right">
  Toggleable section: <button id="spoiler-btn">toggle</button>
  <div id="spoiler">This content can be toggled</div>
  <p>Some other content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @F. Müller. I like the alternative solution but I am unable to implement it in my use case as the toggleable section must slide out to the right. I tried to make my original solution less hacky (here is my modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/3mzdj6hf/2/)). Does this give a better idea of the desired result? The end result is close to what I am after except that I cannot get the yellow box to sit below the red box when the red box is revealed.

Comment: @user51462 something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lg27aw9r/